# How can you back up programs installed for reinstallment

Tags: backup, debian, reinstall

I am wondering if there is a way that I could make a back up of programs or the packages used for installation.

I usually have a handful of programs installed and sometimes I end up having to reinstall my programs whenever I mess something up with the Ubuntu install.  These are either by  'apt-get' or by the GNOME store.  So I cannot install by a '.deb' package for all programs I have.

So I am wondering if there is a way to excract a program or the packages so that if I need to reinstall them, I can easily do so.

Comment: Sure. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages or http://askubuntu.com/questions/694067/make-a-backup-of-the-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-like-linux-mint

Comment: But I would not bother. If I was you I would make a script that holds all your "apt" commands, saved it on a stick and execute that script when you re-install. I did what you asked myself too but newer releases often switch software making your backups obsolete or conflicting with newer software. A script is easier manipulated to exclude stuff. I posted an example of this in 2011: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47404/how-do-i-make-post-install-scripts :)